# Use For each Statement to loop through multi-dimensional Array in VBA Excel - First dimension only

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, loops, foreach

I would like to know if it is possible to loop through a multi-dimensional array and limit the loop to the first dimension only.

I have worked out an example to ilustrate my point:

I use the data I have in excel to create a matrix and I want the loop to print only the values that correspond to the Index column. I have tried different things but nothing seems to work except when using if conditions to exit the for loop.

[Data table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSNaG.png)

Here is the original code:

```
Public matrix1() As Variant

Sub elements_in_loop()

Range("A3").Select
Range(Selection.End(xlToRight), Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
matrix1 = Selection

For Each Record In matrix1

Debug.Print Record

Next

End Sub
```

here is the code with an if condition:

```
Public matrix1() As Variant

Sub elements_in_loop()

Range("A3").Select
Range(Selection.End(xlToRight), Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
matrix1 = Selection

For Each Record In matrix1

    If Record <= UBound(matrix1) Then

        Debug.Print Record
    
    Else:
    
        Exit For
    
    End If

Next

End Sub
```

Any advice on how to do it without an if condition is much appreciated.

Update:

What I need this information for is to look for similar records in two matrices without getting the error "Type mismatch".

Here's the data I'm using:

The record in yellow is the one that is in both matrices.

[data updated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RK5EP.png)

Here is the code I've worked out to get the records that match but is still using if conditionals to limit the search to the first dimension only.

```
Public matrix1() As Variant
Public matrix2() As Variant

Sub elements_in_loop()

Range("A3").Select
Range(Selection.End(xlToRight), Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
matrix1 = Selection

Range("G3").Select
Range(Selection.End(xlToRight), Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
matrix2 = Selection

For Each Record In matrix1

    If Record <= UBound(matrix1) Then
    
            For Each Record2 In matrix2
            
                If Record2 <= UBound(matrix2) Then
                        
                        If matrix1(Record, 4) = matrix2(Record2, 4) Then
                        
                                Debug.Print "There's match"
                                Debug.Print Record
    
                        Else: End If
                Else:
                
                        Exit For
                        
                End If
                
            Next
            
    Else:
    
        Exit For
    
    End If

Next


End Sub
```

Comment: use a normal `For` Loop `For i = Lbound(Matrix,1) to Ubound(Matrix,1)` then you would refer to the item `Debug.Print Matrix(i,1)`

Comment: I'm going to try it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just use a regular for loop and loop the first dimension:

```
Sub elements_in_loop()
    With ActiveSheet
        matrix1 = .Range(.Range("A3").End(xlToRight), .Range("A3").End(xlDown))
        matrix2 = Range(Range("G3").End(xlToRight), Range("G3").End(xlDown))
        
        Dim i As Long
        For i = LBound(matrix1, 1) To UBound(matrix1, 1)
            Dim j As Long
            For j = LBound(matrix2, 1) To UBound(matrix2, 1)
                If matrix1(i, 4) = matrix2(j, 4) Then
                    Debug.Print "There's match"
                    Debug.Print matrix1(i, 4)
                End If
            Next j
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to work with the range directly

See how to set a reference and loop through the first column cells

```
Public Sub elements_in_loop()
    
    ' Define the sheet holding the range
    Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
    Set sourceSheet = ActiveSheet ' This could be a specific sheet like ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet'sName")
    
    ' Set an initial cell
    Dim initialCell As Range
    Set initialCell = sourceSheet.Range("A3")
    
    ' Set the range with Ctrl + Arrows (there are some alternatives like use the range CurrentRegion see below)
    Dim rangeToScan As Range
    Set rangeToScan = sourceSheet.Range(initialCell.End(xlToRight), initialCell.End(xlDown))
    
    ' This replaces the previous line
    'Set rangeToScan = initialCell.CurrentRegion
    
    ' Loop through cells in first column
    Dim sourceCell As Range
    For Each sourceCell In rangeToScan.Columns(1).Cells
            
        Debug.Print sourceCell.Value
    
    Next sourceCell

End Sub
```

Let me know if it works

Comment: Why?  This will be much much slower than iterating an array.

Comment: Performance wise you're right. I just gave an alternative

Comment: @ScottCraner I've worked out a solution with the advice you gave me. It works quite good, thank you.

Comment: @DaveS. see my answer.

Comment: @RicardoDiaz thank you for your alternative as well but I definitely need to work with arrays.